# Why doesn't my End Portal work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making an End Portal in Creative Mode and it won't work. I have a Minecraft combat handbook and I made a portal just like it says to do it.

Do you have to be at a stronghold? I tried lava first and eyes after, but I can't get it to work.

When I point the eyes in the right direction it does not work. The portal cannot be activated, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Screenshot of what you're trying to do would help diagnose why it won't work. The portal should be found in the stronghold, and you need to fill the frames in with eyes.

Comment: @colorfusion he built it in creative

Answer (score 31):

When building an End Portal by yourself, there are several pitfalls to avoid.

1. The portal must be exactly 3X3 blocks large, meaning you need 12 [End Portal Frame](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_portal_frame) blocks.
2. You need to place an [Eye of Ender](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Eye_of_ender) into each block.
3. The End Portal frames must face the center. This is the tricky one. End Portal Frames have [8 block states](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_portal_frame#Block_data), two for each cardinal direction (with/without eye), even though the texture only has two orientations ("wavy" side, "spike" side). The be a valid portal, the blocks on the north side need to face south, the ones on the east must point west, and so on.

   When you place an end portal frame, it will point *towards* you (similar to pistons). To ensure a valid portal, you can place the blocks while standing in the center, facing outwards.

You also need the last eye of ender to be facing inwards for the portal to work.

[image: Self-made end portal indicating block directions]

Comment: BTW: Lava is not needed for End Portals at all, even though naturally generated ones do have a lava pool below them.

Comment: on xbox one that texture seems to be upside down - the lighter part of the eye must point inside

Comment: what texture pack is that?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a portal, try doing it while you are in the middle and placing the blocks all around you.

Comment: This was already stated in a more complete answer over a year ago