# My End Portal isn't working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My Ender Portal isn't forming! I've tried on 5 different worlds and I still can't get my Ender Portal to work.

I'm playing in a 1.9 snapshot.

[image: my end portal]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by it "isn't working"? What are you trying? A screenshot could help.

Comment: Which snapshot exactly?

Comment: Did you place them from inside facing outward or outside facing in? And which snapshot also as there's a known bug related to this, which is why this should be removed as it (possibly) asked about an issue that is not in an official release and is expected to have bugs which will be fixed in final release (we hope).

Answer (score 6):

There's a bug in the 16w02a snapshot, which I presume you're playing, that results in the End Portal not generating.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Ender Portal Frame blocks are in the wrong direction. They're supposed to face the center. Compare yours to this one.

[image: Normal portal]

The frames and eyes are facing the center. Yours are facing a opposite. make sure that the white part of the eyes are facing the center, meaning the portal frame blocks are too!

If it still doesn't work, try building a portal in another world. Another way is to rebuild the portal. People think you need lava underneath, but that's just a decoration. **NOT** important! Other than that, unlike Nether portals, you don't need a flint and steel.

Comment: Nope, they all seem to be facing the correct direction.  End Portals are just broken in the latest snapshot.

Comment: @MBraedley But I noticed that in the askers images, the frames are facing backwards. Here they're facing forward.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  However, that doesn't change the fact that End Portals in general are busted at the moment.

Comment: @MBraedley But I tried to see about this, it doesn't work. They **MUST** be facing to the center!

Comment: @MBraedley [from McLemon's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242645/why-wont-the-end-portal-i-built-in-creative-work?rq=1).

Comment: I really don't care about that, because **all end portals are busted** in the latest snapshot!  I understand what you're saying, but it's immaterial at this point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34423/discussion-between-jim-and-mbraedley).

Comment: Assuming he is using the broken snapshot. He didn't say which he was on that I saw.

Comment: And it can't be determined if the snapshot is the issue until all other factors are corrected. I can't say my video card is broken because I have no image when in fact it is not first connect to power and computer. Either way if it is the broken snapshot this question should be removed. And the frame is inside out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the /fill command to fill the portal frame with portal blocks like this:

```
/fill 200 65 321 203 65 324 minecraft:end_portal
```

So you can use this command to fill your portal, but handle it with extra care, because it can corrupt the frame, structures or even more.
The "raw" command is:

```
/fill X1 Y1 Z1 X2 Y2 Z2 object name
```

Note: X, Y, Z are coordinates. Just replace them with the appropiate ones.

Answer (score -8):

Use a 3x3 pit of lava 1 block under the porta!! That's how I got mine to work on Xbox one edition minecraft!

Comment: This isn't even about Console Edition, though.

Comment: You don't need a pit of lava!

Comment: Lava is for decoration.